# Unexpected touchpad events in `evtest`: is this a driver or kernel or firmware or hardware issue?

Tags: linux-kernel, xorg, drivers, touchpad, asus

**EDIT**: Since I don't know from which component the problem comes (kernel, xorg server, firmware, other?) I have added information from the `xinput --list` command and the `/proc/bus/input/devices` file. Thus I have also edited the list of *tags*. I believe it doesn't come from the driver since testing different xorg drivers (`synaptics`, `libinput`, `mtrack`) doesn't solve the problem, plus the problem can be seen directly in the output of `evtest` which, according to its man page, "shows the information presented by the kernel". But maybe I am wrong?

## ASUS touchpad issue: at new contact after > 1 sec, contact results in slight lag + unexpected double-click event

When the feature 'Tap to click' is enabled in 'Mouse and Touchpad', each time I begin to use the touchpad after having let it unused for > 1 second, the touchpad is slow to react to my first movement (there is a sub-second lag during which the pointer seems stuck) plus it interprets the new contact as a double-click, so that when the pointer finally starts to move I end up creating a selecting frame or dragging whatever was below the pointer when I started moving it.

On the other hand, if I constantly use the touchpad without leaving it at rest for longer than 1 sec, everything works fine: the touchpad reacts instantly at all the commands and it doesn't generate unexpected double-clicks.

I have try to adjust obvious parameters such as the sensitivity, but clearly the problem doesn't come from there.

My questions are:

- Is this a bug (i.e. is this a software issue) and if so at which level can it be (driver, kernel, firmware) ?
- Can it be material (and in particular, can it be in some way related
  to some power management settings that put the touchpad to sleep after
  1 sec) ?
- What can I do next to track the issue ?
- Would anyone have a solution to the problem ?

## Context

I have an ASUS P5440 on which I am trying to install Linux.

I have tested the following distributions and the problem is all the same:

- Linux Mint 19.1 - Cinnamon (kernel 4.15.0-43-generic)
- Ubuntu 18.10
- Manjaro 18.0 - Cinnamon 4.0.1 (kernel: 4.19.4-1-MANJARO)
- Manjaro Gnome 18.0.2
- Manjaro-i3 (Manjaro Linux 18.0 Illyria, kernel: 4.19.2-1-MANJARO)

My problem seems to be the same as this question: [ASUS Zenbook UX430UAR touchpad sleeps (seemingly not a USB autosuspend issue)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464827/asus-zenbook-ux430uar-touchpad-sleeps-seemingly-not-a-usb-autosuspend-issue) but no answer was found.

I tried to use this other question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009812/asus-touchpad-not-working-properly, but in the end the problems seems to be a different one.

On the other side I managed to make some progress in tracking the origin of the problem but now I am stuck.

## Technical information

### Outputs from the `evtest` command

Working in Linux Mint Cinnamon and using the `evtest` command as suggested in a Linux Mint forum [article](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=237206&sid=bb2a19b926f7fe773a21e17c914f5a92), I have obtained the following:

**Touchpad event without issue**

For touchpad contacts giving no issue (i.e. when constantly using the touchpad), the `evtest` output has this structure:

```
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 349
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 480
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 315
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 1
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 480
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 315
Event: time 1547667771.554622, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 0
Event: time 1547667771.554622, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
[...]
Event: time 1547667771.850532, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 307500
Event: time 1547667771.850532, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1547667771.857897, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1547667771.857897, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1547667771.857897, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 0
Event: time 1547667771.857897, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 315000
Event: time 1547667771.857897, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

where the `[...]` indicates a long list of lines of similar sort of content.

What is important to note here is the lines with `BTN_TOUCH` and `BTN_TOOL_FINGER` : associated with the value 1 at the beginning they indicate that a contact has been made, associated with the value 0 at the end they indicate that the contact has been interrupted (when I stop using the touchpad).

**Tochpad event with the issue**

Now, in the case where the problem appears (that is when I contact the touchpad after > 1 sec has passed) the `evtest` outputs the following:

```
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 353
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 642
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 203
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 1
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 642
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 203
Event: time 1547667802.178649, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 0
Event: time 1547667802.178649, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1547667802.179359, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 7500
Event: time 1547667802.179359, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1547667802.184480, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 15000
Event: time 1547667802.184480, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1547667802.191692, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
> Event: time 1547667802.191692, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
> Event: time 1547667802.191692, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 0
Event: time 1547667802.191692, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 22500
Event: time 1547667802.191692, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 354
Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 525
Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 275
> Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
> Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 1
Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 525
Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 275
Event: time 1547667802.221584, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 30000
Event: time 1547667802.221584, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
[...]
Event: time 1547667802.661690, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 472500
Event: time 1547667802.661690, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1547667802.669047, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1547667802.669047, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1547667802.669047, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 0
Event: time 1547667802.669047, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 480000
Event: time 1547667802.669047, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Note the 2 internal events (of 2 lines each), not far below the initial contact, and that I have indicated by `>` signs at the beginning of the respective lines: they correspond to a contact interruption (value 0) and then a contact re-establishment (value 1). It is these two internal events that triggers the initial double-click and that causes the problem.

### Information from the `xinput` command and the `/proc/bus/input/devices` file

Here is the output of `xinput --list` for the touch pad:

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1200:00 0B05:0701 Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

Here is the output from an `xinput --list-props` command:

```
Device 'FTE1200:00 0B05:0701 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (281): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (282): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (283):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (284):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (285):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (286):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (287):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (288):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (289):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (290):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (291):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (292):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (293):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (294):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (295):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (296): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (297):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (298):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (299):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (300):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (301): -0.064777
    libinput Accel Speed Default (302): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (303): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (304): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (266): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (267):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (268):    0, 0
    Device Node (269):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (270):    2821, 1793
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (305):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (306):   0
```

Here are the info from `/proc`:

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
...
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0b05 Product=0701 Version=0100
N: Name="FTE1200:00 0B05:0701 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-FTE1200:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-8/i2c-FTE1200:00/0018:0B05:0701.0001/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20
...
```

### Additional tests

I have also tried to change the driver from `libinput` to `synaptics` using the command `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` as suggested in the page of the [Release Notes for Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tessa_cinnamon.php) but the problem was still there. I have tried to change the driver for `evdev` as indicated in the same page, but after the install I only get `libinput` in the outcome of the command `grep -i "Using input driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log`; removing `libinput` with the command `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput` let me with a non-responding touchpad. I have also tested the driver `mtrack` but the problem is still there.

Comment: As it's visible in `evtest`, whatever is causing it happens in the interaction between the kernel driver and the firmware. Yes, it could be power management issues. The way to debug this further is to identify the kernel driver (via `dmesg` after boot), look at the kernel driver code, enable debugging for it etc.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you very much for your reply.
I found those two lines in the file `/var/log/kernel.log` containing  the term "touch":

kernel: [    4.507490] input: FTE1200:00 0B05:0701 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7/i2c-FTE1200:00/0018:0B05:0701.0001/input/input9

kernel: [    4.507574] hid-multitouch 0018:0B05:0701.0001: input,hidraw1: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [FTE1200:00 0B05:0701] on i2c-FTE1200:00

I am not sure yet how to recognize the name of the driver there.
Also, would you have some hint about how to enable debugging?

Comment: Ok, it's HID over I2C. Read up on both I2C and HID (too long to explain in detail here), on how the kernel handles both and exposes direct interfaces (via `/dev/hidrawX` and `/dev/i2c-*` after `modprobe i2c-dev`). Then you can debug the intermediate stages of the driver stack (e.g. monitor the hidraw device, see if the HID descriptor at `/sys/kernel/debug/hid/<dev>/rdesc` helps in any way) and hope you run across something that will narrow down the problem. Warning: If you are not familiar with any of this, you'll have to do **a lot** of reading. But nobody can debug that without the hardware.

Comment: @dirkt Ok, thanks a lot for all these details. I will look into it, but indeed I am not familiar with any of this, so I don't know how long it will take or if I will even manage to dig further... But I will try. Thanks again.

Comment: By re-enabling the feature 'Tap to click' recently, I realized that the problem was gone. Looking at the most recent kernel log (now in `/var/log/kern.log`), I saw the following: `Nov 23 09:41:50  kernel: [    6.456902] hid-multitouch 0018:0B05:0701.0001: input,hidraw1: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [FTE1200:00 0B05:0701] on i2c-FTE1200:00`. Looking at the numbers, it seems that only the kernel was updated, not the drivers? Also some modules were linked (not shown here). I am not sure what to conclude from those data...

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how to conclude *anything* from the two quoted kernel log lines - `0B05:0701` is the vendor id plus device id, and that hasn't changed. You may or may not have installed a new kernel in the meantime, you may or may not have updated drivers in the meantime, but nobody knows that except you - and you didn't include any old logs or new logs with kernel versions or driver versions to compare.

Comment: Awe. Ok. I found the information. First, I went from Linux Mint 19.1 to Linux Mint 19.2 in August (that might have been an important change). Then, the kernel have been updated several times. It is now 4.15.0-70 (4.15.0-70.79). Also libinput10 and libinput-bin have been updated from 1.10.4-1 to 1.10.4-1ubuntu0.18.04.1. So I guess one of those updates/upgrades solved the bug but difficult to say more at that point. I might try to dig more if I can one day.